# PHP dealing with Invalid argument and expects parameter's

Tags: php

Good Evening, i am trying to teaching myself php, as i go and decided to try build something for our LAN server at work.

i have the following code that works and displays the images from a directory, i am using this as i am building a booking in system for work and naming the image by the job number.

for this i'm naming the images test but having a issue if there inst any images.

```
    <?php

$directory = "saved_images/";


$images = glob("" . $directory . "test*.jpg");

$imgs = '';

foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }




$imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 20);

$result = count($imgs);


if ($result == 0)
{

$img="No Photos";
echo $img;

}
} else {
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
echo "<img src='$img' /> ";
}}
?>
```

the issue is, if there is not any photos i would like it to echo no photos instead of the following errors

```
array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array,
```

refering to this line

```
$imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 20);
```

and

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

refering to this line

```
foreach ($imgs as $img)
```

I have seen someone with a similar problem, but sadly they was advised to ignore the issue and turn off the error reporting, which didn't seem right, I am only asking as this inst causing any problem for the rest of the project and like to know how to fix this problem so if  i encounter it again i know what to do.

Comment: there is an is_array() function in PHP, you could use it before calling the array_slice() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is set `$imgs` as an array (not a string), and check whether `$imgs` is empty or not. While you're at it, you will want to check if `$images` is empty or not, too.

```
$directory = "saved_images/";

$images = glob("" . $directory . "test*.jpg");

// since the entire script relies on $images not being empty,
// we should check for that to be sure before moving on
// you can also test for glob() returning FALSE on error, if you anticipate that it might
if ( ! empty($images) ) {

    $imgs = []; // this should be set as an array, not a string
    foreach ($images as $image)
    {
        $imgs[] = $image;
    }

    if ( empty($imgs) ) {
        echo 'No Photo';
    }
    else {
        $imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 20);

        $result = count($imgs);
        foreach ($imgs as $img)
        {
            echo "<img src='$img'> ";
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo 'No images in ' . $directory . ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you initializing `$imgs` as a string?

```
$imgs = '';
```

and then treating it as an array?

```
foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }
```

If you'd initialize it as an array, e.g.

```
$imgs = array();
```

Then even if the foreach doesn't add anythign to the array, it'll still be an (empty) array when you pass it into `array_slice`.

Basically, you create a pizza, then wonder why PHP is complaining that it's not a chocolate cake.

Answer (score 1):

wrap

```
$imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 20);
```

inside an `if(isset())` statement, like so

```
if(isset($imgs)){
    $imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 20);
}
```

If it still doesn't work add

```
&& count($imgs) > 0
```

to it

Edit:
And what @MarcB said, replace `$imgs = '';` with `$imgs = array();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function `is_array($myArrayVar)` ([PHP Net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)) to test if `$img` is an array before the line where you are using `array_slice($imgs, 0, 20)`. Something like:

```
if (is_array($imgs)){
     // $imgs is an array
} else {
     //$imgs is not an array
}
```